# Does codenameone support liferay screens?

Tags: liferay, codenameone

Liferay screens is available for iOS and android allowing development of native apps using Liferay portal as backend - sort of. Is this supported in codenameone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Unlike Lifray with [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) you only build the UI once to do that you need to use our GUI builder or API both of which would be incompatible with Lifray.